# pip install pygmaps python

Tags: python, pip, pygmaps

I am trying to instal pygmaps for my Python 3.5:

```
pip install pygmaps
```

I am getting this message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygmaps (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pygmaps

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conda install pygmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122492/conda-install-pygmaps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` downloads from PyPI and there is nothing to download from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygmaps

Go to https://code.google.com/archive/p/pygmaps/downloads, download pygmaps-0.1.1.tar.gz, unpack it and install.

Answer (score 5):

You tried to install the old version of pygmaps. Here the newest https://github.com/thearn/pygmaps-extended

For installing from git use this command:

`pip install git+https://github.com/thearn/pygmaps-extended`