# Conda install pygmaps

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda, pygmaps

I am trying to add pygmaps to a school project. I have tried adding it by

```
Conda install pygmaps
```

but it returns

> PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
>
> - pygmaps
>
> We have searched for the packages in the following channels:
>
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch

in the current lab setup pip and conda are the only way to install new packages. Is there anything I am missing?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Does pip install work?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Mark. Then show an error message or at least provide a complete explanation as to why not.

Comment: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygmaps (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pygmaps"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45990573/2988730.

Comment: I've posted an answer that I think addresses your issue now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `pygmaps` is [listed on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygmaps/0.1.1), but not available there for download. The actual code can be downloaded from the [Google code site](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pygmaps/downloads) as a [`.tar.gz` file](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/pygmaps/pygmaps-0.1.1.tar.gz) and installed manually, or even  used in your source code directly, license permitting. You should have permissions to modify the default installation directory if you have the permissions to run `pip`.

It seems that `pygmaps` is no longer being supported, so you may want to check out the extended fork, [`pygmaps-extended`](https://github.com/thearn/pygmaps-extended), which does not appear to even be mentioned on `pypi`, but has a valid `setup.py` file. The following should therefore work:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/thearn/pygmaps-extended
```

This fork hasn't received attention for a while either, but it does have a more recent commit than the original.

The information in this answer is distilled from the answers to [pip install pygmaps python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45990573/2988730).

Comment: Thanks for your idea but I get this "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygmaps (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygmaps"

Comment: IWBN if you check before answering if installable packages exist at PyPI. Because [they don't](https://pypi.python.org/simple/pygmaps/)

Comment: @Mark. Please select this updated answer if it works for you. That way we can close the other question as a duplicate.